# Failed to load dynamic module in Module-federation

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I am getting below error while loading dynamic modules using Module-federation. I have one shell project and another demo project both are in angular v16. I am trying to load Demo project in side shell project using Module federation. Here are the configurations:

Both Demo and shell are different repo built on angular v16

**Demo**
webpack.config

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

name: 'mfe1',

exposes: {
'./Module': './src/app/app.module.ts',
},

shared: {
...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
},

});
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**shell app**
webpack.config

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

remotes: {
"mfe1": "http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",  
},

shared: {
...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
},

});
```

main.ts

```
import { loadRemoteEntry } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

Promise.all([
loadRemoteEntry({
type: 'module',
remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
}),
])
.catch((err) => console.error('Error loading remote entries', err))
.then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
`.routing `{
path: 'dashboard',
// component: DashboardComponent
loadChildren: () =>
loadRemoteModule({
type: 'module',
remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
exposedModule: './Module'
})
.then(m => m.AppModule)
},
```

I am not able to laod the application , it says:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwIGo.png)

I have added the needed config for module-federation as per the documentation [module-federation-plugi](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/tutorial/tutorial.md)

Please can someone help me in debugging it